# Applicaton has stopped error after create instance of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I have a project with some classes.

One class that extends the Activity has a button.
This is the onCreate Method of the class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_car);
/////// some codes and behaviors here
```

Till I arrive at one of my methods that acts on a button.
When the the button is clicked, some data is inserted into my DB,
but before that I want to get a confirmation from the end user that what he selected is corrected or not.
For the first I want to set just a positive answer, here is what I did in that specific Button.

```
            choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//i want to get Confirm from end user, so i did this
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplication());
                builder.setMessage("Are You Sure To do this?")
                        .setTitle("Alert");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

// some data Insert into my DB 
    }
            });
```

When I run my project and achieve this class, I got this error in Android device :

> Unfortunately "MyApplicationName"  has stopped.

And this log from android-studio

```
10-22 18:36:17.910  14478-14478/com.theonlyone.behtakapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.theonlyone.behtakapp, PID: 14478
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:660)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
            at com.theonlyone.behtakapp.Car$5.onClick(Car.java:306)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18796)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What should I do?

Comment: I doubt what is `getApplication()`? So may be you have to change it with `getApplicationContext()` or need to pass Activity Context. And one more thing put your db insertion code in onClick of dialog's button,

Comment: Yes,i show dialog, i forgot to add this into my code.
what should i do?
I Edit my Code.Thx.
Still problem exist

Comment: Use **ActivityName.this** instead of **getApplication()**

Comment: Yeah, you are right.
Thx all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an
>   application

Because passing application context using `getApplication()` in `AlertDialog.Builder`.

To show alert from current Activity which is running pass `Car.this` or `v.getContext()` in `AlertDialog.Builder`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
   choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//i want to get Confirm from end user, so i did this
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setMessage("Are You Sure To do this?")
                           .setTitle("Alert");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // some data Insert into my DB 
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
        });
```